# How to generate data for number (count) of rows in time based on timestamp (createdAt)

Tags: postgresql

I have `Users` table. Each row has field (column) `createdAt` (of type `timestamp with time zone`) which indicates when user has been created. I have to display simple line-chart which will show number of users in time (each day,week or year) in give time period (minDate, maxDate). I know how to group & count users by year for example but then each count will be number of users created in this year and what I want is the number of users created from the beginning till this date. How can I do this in postgres?

---

Here is a code that just returns how many useres were created in each day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "total", date_trunc('day',u."createdAt") as "day"
FROM "Users" u
GROUP BY "day"
ORDER BY "day"
```

[image]

What I need is second row.total to be `199`, third `204`, and so on. So each row total is a `row.toal` + sum of all previous `rows.total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using windowing functions rather than re-querying the data.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "dailyCount", date_trunc('day',u."createdAt") as "day",
sum(count(*)) over( order by date_trunc('day',u."createdAt"))
FROM "Users" u
GROUP BY "day"
ORDER BY "day"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
SELECT day, "dailyCount", "dailyCount" + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users" u2 WHERE date_trunc('day',u2."createdAt") < day) as "totalCount"
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "dailyCount", date_trunc('day',u."createdAt") as "day"
FROM "Users" u
GROUP BY "day"
ORDER BY "day"
) daily
```

[image]